# Get all users that consist bunch of OU with the same names OU=NEEDOU. From a certain database

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm wondering  what I wrote is not correct. I need to get all users that consist of 10-20 OU with the same name OU=NEEDOU. From a certain database.

> Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName -SearchBase "OU=neededOU,OU=Mysearchbase,DC=randomname"|
> where {$_.distinguishedname -like 'OU=NEEDOU*'}

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter "DistinguishedName -like '*OU=NEEDOU*'" -Properties DisplayName`

Comment: @Theo DN can not be filtered like this.

Comment: @filimonic Ah, I forgot.. `DistinguishedName` is a constructed attribute and there only the `-eq` operator is allowed..

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * ... | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*,OU=NEEDOU,*" }
```

You forgot about starting `*` in `-like` operand.

Alternatively you can first search all needed OUs and then get users from them

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '(Name -eq "NEEDOU")' -SearchBase "..." -SearchScope Subtree | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Properties @('...', '...') }
```